# Riesz basis $\{|t|^\alpha e^{int}\}_n$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The class of Riesz bases is very large. It is extremely difficult to exhibit at least one bounded basis for a Hilbert space that is not equvalent to an orthonormal basis. We mention without proof the following example of such a basis in the space $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$: the sequence $\{|t|^\alpha e^{int}\}_n$ with $0<\alpha<1/2$ is a bounded basis for $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ that is not Riesz bases. What is the proof? Any suggepstion please?
Thanks.

Comment: I feel like this is an exercise in patience. Clearly $|t|^{-\alpha} \in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ and we know that $(e^{int})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is a basis for $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. I think it's not hard to argue that $|t|^{-\alpha}g\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ for any $g\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$. From here, make use of standard Fourier to see that it is a basis. I'm not sure how to show it isn't a Riesz basis though.

Comment: Your example  is given in Ivan Singer, *Bases in Banach Spaces*, Vol 1, page 428. The proof that this basis is not a Riesz basis is not trivial (And equivalent to showing it is conditional. Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri state in their monograph that the fact $\ell_2$ has a conditional basis is "by no means obvious"). The original reference is:   Babenko, K. I., On conjugate functions. Doklady Akad. Nauk SSSR $\bf 62$, 157-160 (1948) [Russian].

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another system that is a basis but not a Riesz-basis is $|x|^{-\alpha},|x|^{-\alpha}\cos(x),|x|^{-\alpha}\sin(x),|x|^{-\alpha}\cos(2x),|x|^{-\alpha}\sin(2x),\ldots$. Moreover, this system is neither Besselian nor Hilbertian (in the sense of N.K.Bari) contrary to your system which is Besselian and was constructed by M.S. Altman, 1949 Doklady Akad. Nauk SSSR 69, 483-485.